# VGA to S-Video/Video converter showing mashed up picture

Tags: laptop, tv, vga, adapter, s-video

Earlier I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/132374/does-the-lenovo-t60p-vga-port-support-an-s-video-signal).  As a result I acquired [this item](http://cgi.ebay.nl/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=250588098582&ssPageName=ADME:B:EOIBSA:NL:1123).  It just arrived and now I am trying to get it to work.

The manual is not very informative other than telling me, this is the vga in, this is the vga out, this is the s/video out etc. Plus it tells me the system should support the following resolutions@refresh rate:

- 640x480 @ 60/72/75 Hz
- 800x600 @ 60/75 Hz
- 1024x768 @ 60/75 Hz
- 1280x1024 @ 60 Hz

I can connect it to my laptop and then I connect the S/Video and the Video to my tv which only gives me a blurred image (like when you set your monitor to a resolution it doesn't support). The VGA out however works fine to my tft monitor.

The are two switches on the converter. I think one switches between S-Video and Video and the other between PAL and NTSC. But alas, no combination seems to give a better picture (it does give a different picture).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I have downloaded this program called Powerstrip, but I have no idea how to use it and if it can even solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

I use Windows XP on a Lenovo t60p and I'm trying to connect a Philips 32PFL7403D/12 LCD TV from VGA to a converter to S-Video or Video.

Comment: @matthijs: i have something like that.  haven't actually tried it yet; my expectations for it are not high.  btw, what resolutions/refresh rates is your laptop trying to display at?  you list what the device should do but don't mention what configuration(s) you've tried on your laptop.

Comment: @quack: Thx for fixing the links. I think I have tried with every combination. On the description page on eBay it even said it could handle many more resolutions. I was hoping that I can use Powerstrip to set more refresh rates (lower ones).

Comment: no problem (links)... if you have more links to add, put them in comments, or put them in the post with "hxxp" instead of "http" so the system doesn't recognize them as links.  they can be fixed by a high-rep user.

Comment: First of all even S-Video from a computer out is not very good; second of all not sure the quality of the product you bought; you may try triangle cables; I have bought stuff from them in the past and been satisfyed.  If you are trying to go from a computer to a TV that does not support a monitor cable your best is a video card that accepts TV output however like I say it is not "A good picture" I would clasify it as "Decent" enough to view family photos or video the ODD time.  (get a projector or different TV)

Comment: @Iceking007: I solved the problem through a different route. Together with the Archos 5 Internet Tablet I recently acquired, I also purchased the DVR docking station. This docking station has an HDMI output and the tablet supports a 720p resolution (same as my TV). So now I kind of use my tablet as my media center.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that S-video and composite video are very old formats. They do support resolution up to 480 lines (i.e. 720x480) for the luminance part, but for the color resolution do not expect anything more than 180 lines (vertical).  Thus, what you see may as well be what the analog cable format is capable of.

If you need anything like, or more than, standard definition video signal, then you must invest in TV supporting component video (which uses 3 connectors for video, not to be confused with composite video, which use only 1 connector for video) or direct VGA/DVI inputs.

Good luck.

Comment: My TV supports component I think. Is there an easy/cheap way to convert VGA to Component?

Comment: S-video and composite video support 576 lines with PAL

Answer (score 1):

With the equipment you have now, your best bet is to get a VGA to HDMI [cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TUC64W) and hook it up to your TV.

However, to put it simply, your laptop is old, *very old*.  Generally speaking, you would be much better off buying a newer model laptop with HDMI out.  Getting a full digital signal from laptop to TV will provide the best picture.

Remember, a newer laptop doesnt necessarily mean a *new* laptop.  Craigslist often has great deals on used computer equipment, like laptops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The laptop in question is from summer 2007. So that's old, yes. Btw, I do have a new laptop nowadays (a lot can happen in three years :) ).